# Loading images in the background using CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm working on an app in Swift that uses a UITableViewController with a fixed row height of 200.  I have JPG images stored on CloudKit in a native resolution of 320 x 200.  They range from around 25k to 45k apiece.

The issues I'm having is when the table populates, it loads up the 2-3 cells on the screen with the images and text, as it should.  I'd like the rest of the cells to load in the background, since there are only a total of 12 entries.  In the future there might be as many as 25-30.

As it's working now, when I begin scrolling, the proper text loads into the cells but the images lag a little and load in over the top of a previously display image.

From doing some reading, is this the result of the reusable cell?  Is there a way to load all the cells in the background so it doesn't load the images only after I scroll?

Here's the code I've got:

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return traders.count
}



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    if traders.isEmpty {
        // come back here later
        return cell
    }

    let trader = traders[indexPath.row]

    if let traderDate = trader.objectForKey("modificationDate") as? NSDate {

    //format date

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd hh:mm a"
    var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(traderDate)
    cell.dateLabel?.text = dateString
    }

    cell.nameLabel?.text = trader.objectForKey("StringAttribute") as? String
    cell.placeLabel?.text = trader.objectForKey("Place") as? String
    println(cell.placeLabel.text)

    // Can we can get the image from cache?

    if let imageFileURL = imageCache.objectForKey(trader.recordID) as? NSURL {
        println("Got image from cache")
        cell.traderImageView?.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageFileURL)!)
    } else {

        // OK then, fetch the image from CloudKit in the background
        let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        let fetchRecordsImageOperation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [trader.recordID])
        fetchRecordsImageOperation.desiredKeys = ["image", "detailImage"]
        fetchRecordsImageOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
        fetchRecordsImageOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {(record:CKRecord!, recordID:CKRecordID!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("Failed to get image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let traderRecord = record {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        if let imageAsset = traderRecord.objectForKey("image") as? CKAsset {
                            cell.traderImageView?.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageAsset.fileURL)!)
                            self.imageCache.setObject(imageAsset.fileURL, forKey: trader.recordID)
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
        }

        println("add operation")
        publicDatabase.addOperation(fetchRecordsImageOperation)
    }
    println("return cell")
    return cell
}
```

I'm assuming there must be a way to accomplish what I'm after, and pre-load all the cells with the images.  I've contemplated storing the images as assets in the code itself (which I assume would load faster), but I really want access to change the images through the CloudKit dashboard without having to resubmit a new app each time I want to change an image.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the caching libraries, such as [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache). The lag appears due to several reasons - jpg decoding, loading from disk, some memory issues with Core Animation when the image is not aligned in memory.

I prefer to use FastImageCache, because it is awesome and boosts image loading incredibly. [This](https://bpoplauschi.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/ios-image-caching-sdwebimage-vs-fastimage/) benchmark shows a little advantage of it in case when image is already downloaded and persists on disk.